# MySQL creating a table with 2 different selects

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as not_returned_devices, contact_email FROM device_rent WHERE rent_end IS NULL GROUP BY contact_email;

SELECT COUNT(*) as returned_devices, contact_email FROM device_rent WHERE rent_end IS NOT NULL GROUP BY contact_email;
```

What i need is make a table with 3 columns: contact_name, number of returned devices and number of not returned devices. Basically, what i need is merge those two selects in one table, but im stuck.

Answer (score 0):

Just use conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT contact_email, SUM(rent_end IS NULL) as not_returned_devices,
       SUM(rent_end IS NOT NULL) as returned_devices
FROM device_rent
GROUP BY contact_email;
```

Note that this uses a MySQL short-cut, where boolean expressions are treated as "1" for true and "0" for false.  This is a convenience, and save you from writing a `case` statement.  That would look like:

```
SELECT contact_email,
       SUM(CASE WHEN rent_end IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0
           END) as not_returned_devices,
       COUNT(rent_end) as returned_devices
FROM device_rent
GROUP BY contact_email;
```